# Assign value to a property in bindingcontext in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I wanted to assign a value to a property in bindingContext dynamically.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.dropdown =
 {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
        var param = allBindingsAccessor().dropdownOptions;
        $(element).change(function () {

           //bindingContext[param.Text]= value;
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What is your question?

Comment: I wanted to update an observable value dynamically when a dropdown value is changed. I am giving property name that needs to be assigned value in dropdownOptions

Comment: "options" binding no work for you?

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: why yo go for custom binding, you can use subscribe function right.??